# what is a manifest for?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, manifest

In VisualStudio I have this option for my project to embed a manifest. I have never had to deal with this before and I am curious what it is for.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to pick up custom styles, on XP, among other things. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383%28VS.80%29.aspx).